# Office automation - compress images in ms word addon

Tags: c#, vsto, office-interop, netoffice

I am having some issue trying to compress images from office automation.
I can do this manually:

1. Right click image
2. Select "Format Picture"
3. Picture tab
4. Compress button
5. Apply to "All pictures in document"

I cannot find this method anywhere in the api.
Note: I am using Netoffice as a wrapper for the office automation to bypass version issues, but that shouldn't matter in this particular case because it maps directly to the vsto

I can get a handle on each image, but I am stuck going further.

```
NetOffice.WordApi.Application _wordApplication =   NetOffice.WordApi.Application.GetActiveInstance();
NetOffice.WordApi.Document _wordDoc = NetOffice.WordApi.Application.GetActiveInstance().ActiveDocument;
 List<string> base64StringList = new List<string>();
 _wordApplication.DisplayAlerts = WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone;


            int count = _wordDoc.InlineShapes.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                NetOffice.WordApi.InlineShape shape = _wordDoc.InlineShapes[i + 1];
                shape.Select();
                //figure out some clever way to compress the image
            }
```

Many thanks